# how to make dynamic subdomain for each user registering?

Tags: plugins, users

I am creating a websites where I need to create a seperate sub domain for each user registering on the site.

Ex if the domain name of the site is xyz.com then for user 1 it will be **user1.xyz.com** and for user2 it will be **user2.xyz.com**.

Please guide me how can I achive this functionality

Comment: Please check this 
https://www.codepunker.com/blog/using-php-to-create-new-subdomains-databases-and-email-accounts-on-a-cpanel-driven-server

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using WordPress Multisite (Network) feature.

Please follow this [tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/) for more details.

Hope this will helps you

Comment: I have checked this it. Actually I am creating multivedor plugin for woocommerce such that each vendor can have their own store on a seperate subdomain.